# Deploying to EC2 using Rubber on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubber

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to an Amazon EC2 instance but keeping getting the same error.

```
Trying to enable root login

c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rubber-2.8.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb:173:in `read': No such file or directory - /etc/hosts (Errno::ENOENT)
```

This error points to this block in that file

```
desc <<-DESC
  Sets up local aliases for instance hostnames based on contents of instance.yml.
  Generates/etc/hosts for local machine
DESC
required_task :setup_local_aliases do
  hosts_file = '/etc/hosts'

  # Generate /etc/hosts contents for the local machine from instance config
  delim = "## rubber config #{rubber_env.domain} #{Rubber.env}"
  local_hosts = delim + "\n"
  rubber_instances.each do |ic|
    # don't add unqualified hostname in local hosts file since user may be
    # managing multiple domains with same aliases
    hosts_data = [ic.full_name, ic.external_host, ic.internal_host]

    # add the ip aliases for web tools hosts so we can map internal tools
    # to their own vhost to make proxying easier (rewriting url paths for
    # proxy is a real pain, e.g. '/graphite/' externally to '/' on the
    # graphite web app)
    if ic.role_names.include?('web_tools')
      Array(rubber_env.web_tools_proxies).each do |name, settings|
        hosts_data << "#{name}-#{ic.full_name}"
      end
    end

    local_hosts << ic.external_ip << ' ' << hosts_data.join(' ') << "\n"
  end
  local_hosts << delim << "\n"

  # Write out the hosts file for this machine, use sudo
  *LINE 173* existing = File.read(hosts_file)
  filtered = existing.gsub(/^#{delim}.*^#{delim}\n?/m, '')

  # only write out if it has changed
  if existing != (filtered + local_hosts)
    logger.info "Writing out aliases into local machines #{hosts_file}, sudo access needed"
    Rubber::Util::sudo_open(hosts_file, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(filtered)
      f.write(local_hosts)
    end
  end
end
```

I added the text `*LINE 173*` to the actual line the error is references.

I found this Google Group thread about it, but I'm unsure how to change the path for Windows

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubber-ec2/LFk0NgrOtyY

Any help would be appreciated. Again, I'm trying to deploy Rails app to EC2 instance on a Windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent file in Windows is

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

This code may have difficulties writing to that file since it requires privileged access.